# How to get total hours from start time and end time with multi dimensional array along with over lapping check?

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, time

I have a below scenario where I need to check for the **overlapping** with-in a specific date array only and get total attended hours.

```
array (
  '2020-07-14' => 
  array (
    'total_attended_hours' => 0,
    0 => 
    array (
      'start_time' => '09:00:00',
      'end_time' => '13:00:00',
      'hours' => '4 hours 0 mins',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'start_time' => '13:30:00',
      'end_time' => '16:30:00',
      'hours' => '3 hours 0 mins',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'start_time' => '09:00:00',
      'end_time' => '14:00:00',
      'hours' => '5 hours 0 mins',
    ),
  ),
  '2020-07-15' => 
  array (
    'total_attended_hours' => 0,
    0 => 
    array (
      'start_time' => '13:30:00',
      'end_time' => '17:00:00',
      'hours' => '3 hours 30 mins',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'start_time' => '09:00:00',
      'end_time' => '14:00:00',
      'hours' => '5 hours 0 mins',
    ),
  ),
)
```

As in the above example with date `2020-07-14` we have `start_time and` end_time`:-` total_attended_hours`should be equals to`7 hours 30 mins``

And for next `2020-07-15` it should be `total_attended_hours` = `8 hours 0 mins`

[Playground](https://paiza.io/projects/79afOovCtzTpgsjvtrM_TQ)

**New issue with below array**

```
$data = [
  '2020-07-14' => 
  [
    [
      'start_time' => '14:15:00',
      'end_time' => '17:45:00',
    ],[
      'start_time' => '14:30:00',
      'end_time' => '17:30:00',
    ],[
      'start_time' => '14:30:00',
      'end_time' => '17:30:00',
    ],
  ],
  '2020-07-15' => [
    [
      'start_time' => '13:30:00',
      'end_time' => '17:00:00',
    ],[
      'start_time' => '09:00:00',
      'end_time' => '14:00:00',
    ],
  ],
];
```

Result :-

```
Array
(
    [2020-07-14] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 14:15:00
                    [end_time] => 17:45:00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 14:30:00
                    [end_time] => 17:30:00
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [start_time] => 14:30:00
                    [end_time] => 17:30:00
                )

            [total_attended_hours] => 03:15:00
        )
```

Where as `[total_attended_hours] => 03:15:00` should be `[total_attended_hours] => 03:30:00`

Comment: Can you provide your array via [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) please?

Comment: you should at least show us your try in php, so we can help you

Comment: @Pilan I have updated the question with var_export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you got the algorythm:

1. For each set of Time-Bookings do the following
2. Find the smallest `start_time`
3. Add the `duration` between `start_time` and `end_time` to a `sum`
4. Find the next smallest Time-Booking by `start_time`
5. IF `current_end_time` < `previous_end_time` jump to 4 END IF
6. IF `start_time` < `previous_end_time` subtract difference from `sum` END IF
7. Add `duration` between `start_time` and `end_time`
8. Jump to 4 until there is no matching element left.

Happy coding :)

## EDIT - add more clean implementation

```
function getSortedDays(array $days): array {
    return array_map(function (array $day) {
       array_multisort(array_column($day, 'start_time'), SORT_ASC, $day);
       
       return $day;
    }, $days);
}

function addTotalAttendedHours(array $days): array {
    $sortedDays = getSortedDays($days);
    
    $days = array_map(function (array $day) {
        $sum = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp(0);
        $previousEnd = null;
        
        foreach ($day as $time) {
            $currentStart = new DateTimeImmutable($time['start_time']);
            $currentEnd = new DateTimeImmutable($time['end_time']);

            if ($currentEnd < $previousEnd) continue; // this has been added
            
            $sum->add($currentStart->diff($currentEnd));
            
            if ($previousEnd !== null && $currentStart < $previousEnd) {
                $sum->sub($currentStart->diff($previousEnd));
            }
            
            $previousEnd = $currentEnd;
        }
        
        $attendedSeconds = $sum->getTimestamp();
        $day['total_attended_hours'] = sprintf(
            '%02u:%02u:%02u',
            $attendedSeconds / 60 / 60,
            ($attendedSeconds / 60) % 60,
            $attendedSeconds % 60
        );
        
        return $day;
    }, $sortedDays);
    
    return $days;
}
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/s7PUM).

Comment: I have tried your algorithm and it is giving this result. [Playground link](https://paiza.io/projects/Q2QRKQ7AKyFrts3eAssGdw)

Comment: `$sum -= Helper::getMinsBetweenTwoTimes($item['start_time'], $item['end_time']);` you need the difference between `start_time` and `previous_end_time` - nicely done sir :)

Comment: Thank you so much it would not be possible without your algorithm. You guys are real warriors in COVID-19. I am working home and here we do not have any senior help available than you guys. Really appreciate. Thanks again

Comment: @Php i added a more clean implementation to help you with future code

Comment: I was about to sort dates and you added this wonderful solution thanks a lot mate

Comment: Hey @Pilan Could you help me out I have updated my question it is giving incorrect results in this case